# get scaled width on object:scaling

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I want to get the real object width and height while I am scaling the object. I tried with

```
canvas.on('object:scaling', function(e){
  console.log(e.target.width*e.target.scaleX);
});
```

But seem that does not work properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [object.getScaledWidth()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#getScaledWidth).

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
var circle = new fabric.Circle({radius:100})
canvas.add(circle);
circle.on('scaling',function(){
 console.log(parseInt(this.getScaledWidth()))
})
```

```css
canvas{
  border: 1px dotted green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

Comment: @Druga Thanks, with this, i sloved a new Issue on my program.!

Comment: @PedroJose accept the answer,if it works. Happy coding;)

Comment: @Druga, Works fine, another add question, This function returns values of type 227.86069651741292 ... but, I want you to return entire values 227, is it possible to truncate this number?

Comment: @Druga Do you think it could be beneficial, that this value is truncated, when you give it to a user?
Imagine that you have the ability to create dynamic conditions with javascript, and define a condition for example, that scaleX be 134, but fabric returns 134.44441.

Comment: @PedroJose Sorry, didn't get you.

Comment: Basically, if the user puts a size condition, for example, that the size is 134, but when, as you see in the example, when you resize the object, the getScaledWidth function returns 134.4444.

By the way, there is some way to avoid scaling, if the user leaves a certain place on the canvas, for example, I want to avoid that the user does not scale when the mouse is in a position x> 50 and y> 60